# Проблема с копированием русского адреса сайта

Tags: домен

Подскажите пожалуйста

Сайт зарегистрирован на .рф. Когда копирую из адресной строки эту ссылку, то показывается вид http://xn--80aalb6bk6ah.xn- ... Как-то можно это пофиксить, чтобы даже при копировании красивое название оставалось?

Спасибо..

Comment: на Питоне: [`b'xn--41a.xn--p1ai'.decode('idna')` ->  `'я.рф'`](https://ideone.com/OoDGvz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скажите спасибо убогому хрому. В Firefox, например, все копируется нормально.

Разработчики хрома не только копирования адресов в зоне `.рф` не смогли нормально сделать, более того, при копировании URL на странице вида `https://example.com/русский/путь`, копируется не нормальный русский текст, а какая-то [фигня с процентами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_URL)!

Я пока что копирую адреса так: добавляю в начало адреса пробел, и копирую часть после адреса. Копируется нормально. Но меня это жутко бесит. Прямо сегодня думал о том как они убого это сделали, и что было бы здорово написать им issue об этом, но они, конечно, на нее забьют.